# Run phpMyAdmin on its own user

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I'm having this issue listed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/870949/how-to-deny-apache-access-to-phpmyadmin-config-files) and I was recently told that it is impossible to resolve this issue -- so I had the idea of running phpMyAdmin on its own user (other than Apache's user). I'm running Ubuntu with Apache, is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into LXD and LXC containers. This way you not got to faff about with vhosts, setting up permissions ect, each student gets their own isolated server when they're done, delete it (it will save alot of time too). Also phpmyadmin is not the only db management tool, there is adminer which is much lighter and does not need installing.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Wow, I just saw Adminer. That is super cool, and it's so lightweight! Even better than phpMyAdmin. Thanks for recommending!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because phpMyAdmin is not a process, it's a series of scripts interpreted by a process (either by mod_php running inside Apache or a separate PHP process like php-fpm).